# React navigation header title cut off

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

So basically i'm in the process of learning react native. I'm using the react navigation package and I just want to display a simple header title on my stack navigator but the title cuts off. [Stack nav title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXnUC.jpg)

This is my `App.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import DetailsScreen from './screens/DetailsScreen'

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack)

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return<AppContainer />
  }
}
```

and this is my HomeScreen.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Button, View, Text } from 'react-native'

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Home',
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screeeen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

It doesnt look like this on my friends phones. I'm using a OnePlus 6 with android 9. They are on older versions of android could that be causing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out this is a specific problem affecting OnePlus user who has chosen to use the font OnePlus Slate instead of for exmaple robot. Changing the font in the phone fixes the problem, alternatively you force the usage of a font in the app and it should work as well

Comment: This happens to me as well on a OnePlus 5T, and I didn't change the font myself. Adding `fontFamily: 'roboto'` to `headerTitleStyle` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem running on a OnePlus phone and solved it without the font loader but style with the navigation option in headerTitleStyle width like so:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;



export const MyStackNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tab1: {
      screen: Tab1,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle: `${navigation.state.routeName} page`,
        headerTitleStyle: {
          width: WIDTH - 75,
        },
      }),
    },
    ...more code
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue also occurs in various components like button in one plus devices. One way to solve it by giving some minimum width to the label style, so that you don't have to switch the font family, helps if you are using some custom fonts

Solution: `width: '100%'` or some fixed value like `minWidth: 100`

Code example in drawer navigation

```js
<DrawerItem
    labelStyle={{ minWidth: 100 }}
    label={`Orders`}
    onPress={() => {}}
 />
```